# When 2% of the Bayesian Model have not converged?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, gibbs

I have model with 20000 latent parameters, set up in a Gibb's sampler.

98% of the parameters and sometimes 99.5% of the parameters satisfy the Geweke convergence statistic, have low autocorrelation at a lag of 10 and have a good effective sample size.

My parameters of interest are in the 98%. Running the chain to 100000 iterations doesn't really change much. What are my options?

Similar to this one

[If all components of a hierarchical model have not converged, can we say that any parameters have truly converged?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196606/if-all-components-of-a-hierarchical-model-have-not-converged-can-we-say-that-an)

and

[Latent variables, overparameterization and MCMC convergence in bayesian models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35530/latent-variables-overparameterization-and-mcmc-convergence-in-bayesian-models)

Comment: What do you want to do with the output from the Gibbs sampler? If the interest is in estimating the a sample mean of a function, then the estimator is consistent irrespective of starting value. So you won't even have to worry about convergence of the chain, as long as you have enough Gibbs samples.

Comment: If you run $20,000$ tests of null hypotheses that all holds, what is the average number of times you will reject these hypotheses?

Comment: Hi Xi'an, If I ran 20000 chains for the same parameter, I should expect to see a normal distribution on a convergence score. Note, in a regression model with say 10 parameters, we would treat inferences from the model with even one unconverged parameter as dubious.  There are a significant number in the semi parametric models I work with and the issue is that Gibb's samples for converged parameters rely on full conditionals of these "unconverged" estimates. The question is can we rely on these tainted results?

Comment: Isnt the whole point that the inability to reject convergence helps us believe we may have attained a stationary distribution (though not definitively)?